# how to open a function in a new window

Tags: php, function, window

OK so I have a function, basically what it does is to echo a table of the object given.

lets say:

```
<?php
function print($obj)
{
 print_r($obj);
}
...
```

so if call print, it and it will print the object. But now I want to have this object printed in a new window. How would I do that, without making the function its own php page and passing variables to it ?

Comment: What language is this?  Edit your question to use the proper language tag to get more eyeballs on your question.

Comment: @Degar007 I guess it's PHP, right? Since opening new window is the responsibility of client-side scripting (e.g. JavaScript), you probably need to write much more than this.

Comment: Assuming are you talking about server side PHP and not, for instance, PHP-GTK+ - you can't. Browsers don't work like that.